# Open Print Dialog in App through Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, airprint

i am very new to iOS programming and encountered a issue. I have a pdf i want to print off the internet. How do i print this through my app without a third-party app? Also, i have heard about apple's AirPrint, and that it is pre-installed on the iOS device. How would i use that? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.H File Code

```
 #import
    @interface xyviewController : UIViewController <...,UIPrintInteractionControllerDelegate> {

    UIPrintInteractionControllerDelegate should be delegate
    }
    -(IBAction)printdoc;
```

.M File Code

```
-(IBAction)printdoc
{



NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"demo" ofType:@"jpg"];
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: path];


UIPrintInteractionController *pic = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];

if(pic && [UIPrintInteractionController canPrintData: myData] ) {

pic.delegate = self;

UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
printInfo.jobName = [path lastPathComponent];
printInfo.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplexLongEdge;
pic.printInfo = printInfo;
pic.showsPageRange = YES;
pic.printingItem = myData;

void (^completionHandler)(UIPrintInteractionController *, BOOL, NSError *) = ^(UIPrintInteractionController *pic, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
//self.content = nil;
if (!completed && error) {
NSLog(@"FAILED! due to error in domain %@ with error code %u", error.domain, error.code);
}
};

[pic presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];

}

}
```

Comment: thanks! hey..also, how would i print this pdf? Also, when i display it in a webview, why is it not scaled? http://laurelchristian.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Lunch-Menu-February-2013.jpg